# Problems with Modularizing and Value-Returning Methods

Tags: c#, methods

I'm very new to C#, passing arguments, modularizing and value-returning methods are pretty tought for me.

I'm trying to get two buttons to interact with each other.

One button has a counter on it. Each time it is clicked a variable that has started out with 1 gets added another one.

And the other button displays the number that the counter on the other button is on.

I hope this makes sense.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private int TotalCount(int count)
    {
        return count += 1;
    }

    private void buttonCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalcount;
        int count;

        totalcount = TotalCount(ref count);

        MessageBox.Show("The number clicked is: " + totalcount);
    }
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

As Garry Vass points out reference arguments are not needed in this case however if you are using reference arguments both the definition and the calling of the method needs to specify ref

```
 private int TotalCount(ref int count)
 {
        return count += 1;
 }
```

Here is a reference that explains the ref keyword more completely.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make 'count' an instance variable...

```
int count = 0;
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
private int TotalCount()
{
    ++count;
    return count;
}

private void buttonCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalcount = TotalCount();

    MessageBox.Show("The number clicked is: " + totalcount);
}
```

You were declaring 'count' as a local variable, so it was being initialized on each entry to the method, thus the value was not persistent.  Reference arguments are not needed in this case, so they have been removed.

Comment: Yes I missed the scoping issue in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Although Gary Vass is correct that count needs to be an instance variable, I wouldn't consider his answer as the right way to go about coding it.

Method names are critically important, especially as a code base grows, and you should follow the principle of "least astonishment".  In this case the name of a method should indicate what it will do and it shouldn't have hidden side effects.  See http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2006/02/27/9590.aspx

The name `TotalCount`  implies that it will return the total count.  Nothing about that name indicates that it is actually going to modify data.

The route I would take is:

```
int count = 0;

private int IncrementCount() {
  count++;
  return count;
}

private void buttonCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalcount = IncrementCount();

    MessageBox.Show("The number clicked is: " + totalcount);
}
```

The difference is subtle.  However, someone glancing through *just* the buttonCount_Click method would have a pretty good idea what `IncrementCount()` does without actually having to investigate that code.

Comment: I changed my code to exactly this and for some reason it only increments (and displays it) when the count button is clicked. I need it to increment when another button is pressed. And the count button will only display that number.